# Passing data between angular 1.5 module in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, module, parent, pass-data

How can I pass data from A parent module to A child module in typescript angular 1.5 using require property

Comment: what do you mean by using require property?

Comment: Exampleequre{tabsctrl:^mytabs}

Comment: explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication) pretty well

Comment: Yes aleksey i need the code explained in the link what you have mentioned in typescript